# Where is the map file between the schema of database and the Yii class CActiveRecord?

Tags: yii

I use the gii to generate the CActiveRecord classes when building a web site with the help of Yii. Then the content of database can be visited via the object of the corresponding class. Here is my question: where is the map file between the schema of the database and the Yii class CActiveRecord? I have checked all the files in the web project and find no such file.

Answer (score 2):

I believe CActiveRecord actually queries the system schema tables in the database rather than storing a file with the schema that gii detected.  This is why you can simply add a new column to a table and then reference it in your model's views without having to update the model (unless you want to set the attribute label for it).

Comment: +1, on a side note, is that one of the reasons, why activerecords are considered slow?

Comment: Is there way to use a schema file instead of query the database? When I use the gii. I should choose the table which the CaActiveRecord  class maps to, so where is these information stored?

Comment: @jerry_sjtu: you can use [CDbConnection.schemaCachingDuration](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbConnection#schemaCachingDuration-detail) to cache the schema for a certain period of time. Strongly recommended for any production site.

[CActiveRecord.tableName](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#tableName-detail) is used to determine the corresponding table name.